# App crashed when send via third party app like bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio

App is crashed when send via shareit but run on the device by usb debugging. This problem occurs after updating my Android Studio plugins, version etc.

**module:app file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sonu.check"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
 }
 }
  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Do you have logs? please share it. And may be you are sharing content whitch is not supported by shareit so it crashed your app !!

Comment: Can you please share you LogCat error if there is any ?

Comment: 08-18 15:31:02.240 30264-30600/com.example.sonu.chatt E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9f2e080